# IStringLocalizer with third party DI

Tags: simple-injector, asp.net-core-localization

I'm trying to setup localization following this documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization

I assume that if you use the built in DI it just works however I'm using Simple Injector instead of the build in DI in so it complains that I haven't registered the IStringLocalizer. How do I go about registering IStringLocalizer as I obviously can't do this

```
container.Register<IStringLocalizer, StringLocalizer>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get localization working in ASP.NET Core, you will have to call `AddLocalization()` from within your `ConfigureServices` method and enable *auto cross-wiring*:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    services.AddLocalization(); // ** Add localization to ASP.NET Core **

    // Normal MVC stuff
    services.AddMvc();

    // Simple Injector integration
    IntegrationSimpleInjector(services);
}

private void IntegrationSimpleInjector(IServiceCollection services) {
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    services.AddSingleton<IControllerActivator>(
        new SimpleInjectorControllerActivator(container));

    services.EnableSimpleInjectorCrossWiring(container);
    services.UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping(container);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {

    // This call allows Simple Injector to resolve anything from ASP.NET Core.
    container.AutoCrossWireAspNetComponents(app); // ** Enable auto cross-wiring ***

    // NOTE: If you're still running .NET Core v1.x, auto cross-wiring will not be
    // available. In that case, you can make the following call to CrossWire<T>
    // to register StringLocalizer<T>'s dependency explicitly.
    // container.CrossWire<IStringLocalizerFactory>(app);

    // Your usual startup stuff here
}
```

The call to `services.AddLocalization()` adds to appropriate registrations to the ASP.NET Core configuration system, but that by itself doesn't allow Simple Injector to get to it. Simple Injector v4.1 however contains an `AutoCrossWireAspNetComponents` extension method that allows the container to go look for missing dependencies in the ASP.NET Core configuration system.

This is all you need to get things up and running, but we can do better...

Because of limitations in the built-in ASP.NET Core DI container, you are forced to inject generic abstractions such as `ILogger<T>` and `IStringLocalizer<T>` where `T` will *always* be the consuming type itself. What this means is that when such dependency required in `HomeController`, you need to inject an `ILogger<HomeController>` and `IStringLocalizer<HomeController>`. It would be much cleaner, more maintainable, and safer to be able to inject the non-generic `ILogger` and `IStringLocalizer` abstractions, and let the DI container automatically find the correct generic implementation to implement.

Unfortunately, the built-in DI container does *not* support this. But most mature DI libraries actually *do* support this, as does Simple Injector.

The following registration, allows any application component to depend on the non-generic `IStringLocalizer` and Simple Injector will inject a generic `StringLocalizer<T>` where `T` becomes the consuming type, thus still getting a localizer for *that particular* class.

```cs
container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(IStringLocalizer),
    c => typeof(StringLocalizer<>).MakeGenericType(c.Consumer.ImplementationType),
    Lifestyle.Singleton,
    c => true);
```

With this registration, your `HomeController` can no depend on `IStringLocalizer` as shown below:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer localizer;

    public HomeController(IStringLocalizer localizer)
    {
        this.localizer = localizer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Steven, that all makes sense however I get the following error about IServiceScope not being registered?

ActivationException: The constructor of type StringLocalizerProxy<HomeController> contains the parameter with name 'scope' and type IServiceScope that is not registered. Please ensure IServiceScope is registered, or change the constructor of StringLocalizerProxy<HomeController>.

Comment: Did you call `EnableSimpleInjectorCrossWiring`?

Comment: Yes I did - Is it possible that automapper with its IMapper is causing a issue. I never had EnableSimpleInjectorCrossWiring before and was using IMapper and then had to update simple injector to get EnableSimpleInjectorCrossWiring

Comment: I just created a new project and just added your code and still getting the same error so nothing in there to clash. Any ideas?

Comment: @Michael: Crap! I see the problem. `IServiceScope` gets registered when the first `CrossWire` is done for a non-singleton service. Give me a sec, will get back to you on this.

Comment: @Michael: See my update. You will have to add the `IServiceScope` registration yourself. This is typically done when calling `CrossWire`, but you don't seem to have any scoped or transient CrossWirings.

Comment: Working perfectly! Thanks for the assistance

Comment: Updated my answer. It now uses the new `AutoCrossWireAspNetComponents` and shows how to make a contextual registration to allow application components to depend on the non-generic `IStringLocalizer` instead.

Comment: @Alisson: ASP.NET Core 2.x does run on .NET FX as well, and I believe that the new localization features can be used outside the context of ASP.NET Core and .NET Core as well.

Comment: @Steven it seems Simple Injector v4.1 is only compatible with .NET Core 2.0 and above, so I wasn't able to use this solution in a .NET Core 1.1 project. When simple injector DI's tries to create `StringLocalizer` class, it has a dependency to `IStringLocalizerFactory`. I also tried registering `IStringLocalizerFactory` with its implementation `ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory`, but it also has more dependencies. I guess all those dependencies is what the cross wire methods resolve, but these methods are not available on older versions of Simple Injector.

Comment: You can use the [latest 4.0.x](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore/4.0.12) release of the ASP.NET Core integration packages together with @user844705's answer. The 4.0.x integration packages for ASP.NET Core are compatible with .NET Core v1.x.

Comment: @Steven thanks, I'm gonna give a try. Tbh I'm considering upgrading to .NET Core 2.1. It's a small legacy project. But it's nice for other bigger 1.1 projects I have which would require more effort to upgrade.

Comment: @Alisson: I updated my answer to include this information.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I came across this post looking to do the same thing, but I took a different approach based on the ILogger registration I used. So here is what I do to get strongly typed IStringLocalizers in my controllers and services.

Cross-wire the StringLocalizerFactory

```cs
container.CrossWire<IStringLocalizerFactory>(app);
```

Then use `RegisterConditional`

```cs
container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(IStringLocalizer),
    c => typeof(StringLocalizer<>).MakeGenericType(c.Consumer.ImplementationType),
    Lifestyle.Singleton,
    c => true);
```

And then I can inject the non-generic IStringLocalizer into my controllers etc and it will be of the correct type. For example, if I use the following constructor

```cs
public MyController(IStringLocalizer localiser)...
```

Then localiser will be of type

```cs
IStringLocalizer<MyController>
```

This is with ASP.NET Core MVC 2 & Simple Injector 4.1. I wonder if [steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven) has any comment on this approach?

Comment: This is almost the exact approach I describe in my answer. However, instead making use of auto cross-wiring to inject the `IStringLocalizerFactory` into the `StringLocalizer<T>`, you cross-wire `IStringLocalizerFactory` explicitly by making use of the `CrossWire<T>` extension method. The effect is the same and your approach is as valid as mine.